# Empty array as PostgreSQL array column default value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a defined an array field in postgresql 9.4 database:

```
character varying(64)[]
```

Can I have an empty array e.g. {} for default value of that field? 
What will be the syntax for setting so?

I'm getting following error in case of setting just brackets {}:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...public"."accounts" ALTER COLUMN "pwd_history" SET DEFAULT {}
                                                                     ^

In statement:
ALTER TABLE "public"."accounts" ALTER COLUMN "pwd_history" SET DEFAULT {}
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You need to use the explicit `array` initializer and cast that to the correct type:

```
ALTER TABLE public.accounts 
    ALTER COLUMN pwd_history SET DEFAULT array[]::varchar[];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I've found another solution too, although don't know which is one more "correct" `pwd_history SET DEFAULT '{}'`.
But as I understand both solutions are resulting the same casting for postgresql (explicit/implicit).

Comment: Just as a note for anyone trying to create a default value via SqlAlchemy (for python): you have to use `{}` for default value in the ORM mapping, e.g. `sizes = Column(postgresql.ARRAY(postgresql.TEXT), server_default="{}")` and let it do the implicit conversion, as mentioned in @Hett comment above

Comment: I've done this with success `ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar SET DEFAULT '{}';`

Comment: I realise the op asked specifically about Pg 9.4, but this might be useful for users of newer versions. Just set the default as the following constant: `{}`. This would be the DDL:

`my_array_column text[] DEFAULT '{}'::text[]`

Answer (score 65):

I tested both the accepted answer and the one from the comments. They both work.
I'll graduate the comments to an answer as it's my preferred syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE public.accounts 
    ALTER COLUMN pwd_history SET DEFAULT '{}';
```

Answer (score 6):

It threw an error where it can not find `SET`. This worked for me.

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.accounts 
    ALTER COLUMN pwd_history DEFAULT array[]::varchar[];
```