# How to set an Array column with an empty array as default in SQLAlchemy + Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to list the `sources` of a piece of information. Instead of creating another table with a `one to many` relation, I tought I'd use the `Array` type.

To I tried:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

...

class Edge(db.Model):

    sources = db.Column(
        db.ARRAY(db.String),
        default=db.ARRAY(db.String)
    )
```

But adding an `edge` gives me this error:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'ARRAY' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO edges (child_id, parent_id, sources) VALUES (%(child_id)s, %(parent_id)s, %(sources)s'] [parameters: {'child_id': 20, 'parent_id': 26, 'sources': ARRAY(String())}]

I can't find a good tutorial on how to use an `array` column with a default  empty array.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I eventually found the answer in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933266/empty-array-as-postgresql-array-column-default-value):

```
sources = db.Column(
    db.ARRAY(db.String),
    server_default="{}"
)
```

Comment: I wonder how to do this in the new declarative world of  `Mapped[list | None]`

Answer (score 2):

A python callable can also be set as default value:

```
sources = db.Column(
    db.ARRAY(db.String),
    default=dict
)
```